# Show Svelte Component for Only 1 Element In #Each Block

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

I have an #each block, showing an image and text. If a user clicks a button, I want to show a component on that specific image, not all images. Right now, I have something like the following, so #if loading, show the LoadingSpinnger component. This shows on all images, not just the one clicked. Is there a way to add a component inside a div so it doesn't apply to all images?

```
 {#each things as thing}
        <div class="image">
          {#if loading}
            <LoadingSpinner />
          {/if}
          <img
            src={thing.p}
            id ={thing.id}  />
        </div>
      <div class="info">
        Name: {thing.n} Species: {thing.s}
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button on:click={addComponent()}>
          Button Text
        </button>
      </div>
  {/each}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you would want the LoadingSpinner and the image to be in one seperate component, that way the _loading_ will be only applied to that image

Comment: Not sure if I could do that, because I'm using the unique thing.id as part of the image source. So it's like `src: /img/users/{user.id}/{thing.id}/image`. I'm not sure if I want to mess with extracting all that into a component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joshnuss answer works as well, but I needed to keep the loading variable as a true/false value because it toggled other variables. So I just added a new variable, `thingLoading`, and used it like so:

```
{#each things as thing}
    <div class="image">
      {#if loading && thingLoading === thing.id}
        <LoadingSpinner />
      {/if}
      <img
        src={thing.p}
        id ={thing.id}  />
    </div>
  <div class="info">
    Name: {thing.n} Species: {thing.s}
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button on:click={addComponent()}>
      Button Text
    </button>
  </div>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `loading` variable is not tied to any specific image.

To track the loading state for each `thing`, use an dictionary keyed by `thing.id`.

Then check the `loading` dictionary with `thing.id`:

```js
{#each things as thing}
  {#if loading[thing.id]}
    <LoadingSpinner/>
  {:else}
    <img src={thing.src}/>
  {/if}
{/each}
```

Comment: Ah yes, that would work! I kept loading as true or false thought, because it also toggles other things. Instead I loaded thing.id into a variable `thingLoading`, and then used `    {#if loading && thingLoading === thing.id}` which did the trick. Thanks for the help!